# How can I create a regex pattern than spans multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have a long regex pattern that I want to split over multiple lines.

Is there a way to take

```
$s !~ m"((\d)|(\d))";
```

and split it so you get something like

```
$s !~ m"((\d)|"+
"(\d))";
```

The above guess is incorrect and results in

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE (\d)|/ at perl5.pl line 20.
```

What can I use?

Comment: Did you mean to use `.` instead of `+`?

Comment: Continuation of the literal. The code is actually written over 2 lines.
Without continuation "$s !~ m"((\d)|(\d))"

Comment: Please, show us the code. `$s !~ m"((\d)|(\d))"` doesn't throw any errors and is better written `$s !~ "\d";`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: As I mentioned, I simplified the regex to illustrate the problem, namely when a regex is written over two lines with 3 (() brackets in the first line and the matching 3 ()) brackets in the second line, the regex parser issues the inappropriate error message.
        $s !~ m"((\d)|"+
        "(\d))";
Despite me indenting the code, SO insists on writing the code on one line.

Comment: I can't imagine why one would select `"` as the regex delimiter for an expression that has `"` literal characters in it. Coding for clarity would dictate not to do that.

Comment: Why was this closed?!?

Comment: @DavidO, The `"` is not part of the pattern; they're trying to split the pattern over two lines. (The OP thinks `m"..." + "..."` is the same thing as `m"......"`)

Answer (score 3):

You can't split a pattern into two like that. You can however have a single pattern spread neatly over multiple lines by using the /x modifier to tell the regex parser to ignore whitespace. For example:

```
$s !~ m{
         ((\d)
         |
        (\d))
    }x;
```

Comment: I am afraid this did not help -> same error.

Comment: @TonyR, You are mistaken. Dave Mitchell's code is valid, so you must have used something different.

Comment: I used "s to emphasize grouping, so my situation is somewhat different and OK provided unbalanced brackets are specified.

Comment: @TonyR, Your situation is not different. `/x` allows you to write a pattern that spans multiple lines, period. You do need to escape whitespace you want to match literally or place it in a character class, but you can otherwise do anything you could normally do, just over multiple lines. Specifically, the choice of delimiter is irrelevant.

Comment: The difference and problem was the +-continued literals. 
It is strange with regex so well integrated in Perl that it does not handle this structure correctly.

Comment: As has been pointed out, in Perl you use '.' rather than '+' to concatenate strings, and you can't concatenate patterns.